# ng-repeat with trackby and ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I have a table which has an an `ng-if` on a `<tr>` depending on some value.

My code looks like this:

```
<tr ng-if="someConditional" ng-repeat="row in rows track by row.obj1">....</tr> 

<tr ng-if="!someConditional" ng-repeat="row in rows track by row.obj2">....</tr>
```

This gives me an error though when `row.obj1` exists and `row.obj2` doesn't and vice versa.

row.obj1 exists for when someConditional is true, and row.obj2 exists for !someConditional is true.

When the someConditional is true, angularjs throws an error that row.obj2 doesn't exist (i.e not defined).

Is this a known bug? and is there any workaround for this?

Comment: It's difficult to understand your question: what error are you getting? What are the values? I suggest you write a JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you roll the conditional into the ng-repeat?

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows track by (someConditional ? row.obj1 : row.obj2)">....</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) has a higher priority than [`ngIf`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) (see the "Directive Info" section of each link). In other words, the output won't be:

```
if condition then
    foreach
        ...
    endforeach
endif
```

But rather:

```
foreach
    if condition then
        ...
    endif
endforeach
```

One solution would be here to use only one `ng-repeat` statement, and nest the conditions within this loop.

Comment: even so, how would track by work if my object is different based on some condition?